# VM Instance GCP doesn't appear when creating an instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I want to create an instance group with my wordpress instance, and it doesn't appear the option to choose my instance. It show "No available VMs". Does someone know what can I do?

[image: print showing instance group]

Comment: can you add more detail on your configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unmanaged instance group is a collection of virtual machines (VMs) that reside in a single zone, VPC network, and subnet. It is useful for grouping together VMs that require individual configuration settings or tuning.

To answer your question, you must first create a [VM instance](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) so that it will be visible when you create an Unmanaged Instance Group.
However, keep in mind that under VM instance you can only choose a VM if you are in the same zone, VPC network, and subnet as existing VMs.

You can also refer to this [creating a group of unmanaged instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances#create_unmanaged_group) and this [add instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances#addinstances).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot, it seems that you haven't chosen any on the Network drop-down field. According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances#group_membership), you can only group VMs together if the first or only network interface (nic0) of each VM is attached to the same VPC network. Choose first on the Network field, and then the VMs under the chosen VPC network should be available.